# MS SQL query optimization

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I experiencing performance issues with pretty simple query.

```
--All Windows Servers
with t1 (Name, [OS Name]) as
(
(select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo where [OS Name] like '%windows%server%')

union all

--All non-Windows Servers
(select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo
except
select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo where [OS Name] like '%windows%')
)

select distinct ci.guid,t1.Name, t1.[OS Name],
    'System Type' = case
        when ci.[System Type] = ''
        then 'Unknown'
        else ci.[System Type]
    end, 
    'Virtualization Status' = case
        when (ci.guid in (select guid from VirtualMachineInfo))
        then 'Virtual'
        else 'Physical'
    end,
ci.Server
from t1
join ComputerInfo ci on t1.Name = ci.Name
order by t1.Name
```

The idea is that i select and separate virtual and physical servers by using existing inventory data that stored in our DB. The issue is that this query runs very, VERY slowly even on test DB needless to say about production.

I understand that probably i have chosen not optimal way to get the data i want, but unfortunately because of lack of skills i'm unable to rewrite or optimise this query.

I really appreciate any help, and would be glad to see any advice.

Comment: How much control do you have over the database design?

Comment: Hi Pieter, i'm DBA and can create new tables\views or modify existed.

Comment: why can't you change the following query

(select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo
except
select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo where [OS Name] like '%windows%')
)

To:

select Name, [OS Name] from ComputerInfo where [OS Name] not like '%windows%'

Comment: @ps_prakash02 That's a good question. I think exeption was added in previous version of this query where was a few joins or something like that. Thank you for noticed this.

Comment: The way I remember it works with a query like that, is that everything in your "AS" block will be executed for every resultrow in your join. That in combination with a LIKE in your select will make things very slow.

Comment: @PieterB Uhm, is there any different way to represent AS-block for less resource usage?

Comment: One thing coming to mind is to have all different operating system versions in their own table.